# TV Guide script - getting current date programmes to show

Tags: php, sql, mysql, apache

This is part of my TV guide script:

```
       //Connect to the database
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","PASSWORD");
   //Select DB
   mysql_select_db("mytvguide");

   //Select only results for today and future
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT programme, channel, episode, airdate, expiration, setreminder FROM mediumonair where airdate >= now()");
```

The episodes show up, so there are no issues there. However, it's getting the database to find data that's the issue.

If I add a record for a programme that airs today this should show:

```
Medium   showing on TV4   8:30pm    "Episode"    Set Reminder
Medium  showing on TV4  May 18th - 6:25pm  "Episode 2"  Set Reminder
Medium  showing on TV4  May 18th - 10:25pm  "Episode 3"  Set Reminder
Medium  showing on TV4  May 19th - 7:30pm  "Episode 3"  Set Reminder
Medium  showing on TV4  May 20th - 1:25am  "Episode 3"  Set Reminder
Medium  showing on TV4  May 20th - 6:25pm  "Episode 4"  Set Reminder
```

but this shows instead:

```
    Medium  showing on TV4  May 18th - 6:25pm  "Episode 2"  Set Reminder
Medium  showing on TV4  May 18th - 10:25pm  "Episode 3"  Set Reminder
Medium  showing on TV4  May 19th - 7:30pm  "Episode 3"  Set Reminder
Medium  showing on TV4  May 20th - 1:25am  "Episode 3"  Set Reminder
Medium  showing on TV4  May 20th - 6:25pm  "Episode 4"  Set Reminder
```

I almost have the SQL working; just not sure what the right code is here, to avoid the second mistake showing - as the record (which indicates a show currently airing) does not seem to work at present.

Please can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the query that produced the above incorrect results? Can you provide more details about the schema?

Comment: The schema is MySQL/InnoDB, and the query is:
http://pastebin.com/qRLFUK4x
(linked for convenience)



Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, but I would guess there's something strange about the way that you are storing your date and time in the airdate column. Try running a query like this so you can do the same comparison you're asking the database to do:

```
select now(), airdate from mediumonair where episode = 'Episode'
```

Comment: The airdate column is stored as DATETIME, so I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: You don't understand why what happens, @whitstone86 ? What does the result look like when you run the query I suggested?

Comment: I've got a blank area, no results.

Comment: It could be that the database server is storing the DATETIME based on Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), rather than local time.  If there's enough difference, that would explain why the first row was missing from the retrieval.

Comment: I suggest you look directly in the database to see how the airdate is stored. Do you have phpMyAdmin or some other database tool that can directly query your database? If you can't get that working, then using var_dump() to look at the query results would be the next best thing.

Comment: I do use phpMyAdmin for it, and it's stored as DATETIME.
Tried setting timezone but had no luck with it.

Will try var_dump() and let you know if it works!

Comment: Try using phpMyAdmin to run the query I posted. Then you can compare the stored airdate and the now() function yourself.